# Add Spring boot into my spring mvc hibernate application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I would like to migrate  my `spring mvc hibernate configuration` into
`spring boot`.
I am attaching my configuration file which is used to `beans configuration`. But i want to play with Spring boot.  Please help me to migrate my application in Spring boot .

**Config.java**

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.TemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String dbDriver;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String dbUrl;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String dbUserName;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hbmddl;

    @Value("${message.basename}")
    private String baseName;

    @Value("${message.encoding}")
    private String encoding;

    @Value("${hibernate.connection.datasource}")
    private String datasource;

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    public XmlViewResolver XmlViewResolver() {

        XmlViewResolver xmlViewResolver = new XmlViewResolver();
        return xmlViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolverForRedirect() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        resolver.setViewNames(new String[] { "redirect*" });
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        // commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1048576);
        commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10000000);
        return commonsMultipartResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");

        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        resource.setBasename(baseName);
        resource.setDefaultEncoding(encoding);
        return resource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(getDataSource());

        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(com.aaaa.Example.class);

        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);

        if (datasource!=null && !datasource.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.datasource",datasource);
        }

        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbmddl);


        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriver);
        dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUserName);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(getSessionFactory());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfig() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just add the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency to your pom file and get rid of this configuration. The jpa starter provides an underlying Hibernate implementation which is configurable from your application.properties file. Take a look at the jpa properties of boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 2):

First modify your pom and add the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artificatId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

And add the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` as a plugin to your build.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now you have the basic build blocks and you can start adding Spring Boot starters and reduce your configuration. First add a the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    < artifactId >spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now you can remove the `javax.servlet` and `spring-web`dependencies those will be added by the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency.

Now you need a starter class to have an embedded container running.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(Config.class) 
public class YourApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now you have a Spring Boot application with an embedded tomcat. Spring Boot should be smart enough in detecting which beans are already there and which dependencies you have.

Now you can start removing things from your configuration and let Spring Boot handle them for you.

First you can remove the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean as Spring Boot already provides that. You can also remove the `@PropertySource` as Spring Boot already loads that by default. The same applies to `@EnableTransactionManagement`.

Now the easiest thing to do is to start with the datasource. Rename the `db.*` properties to `spring.datasource.*` properties. This will let Spring Boot know you want it to configure a `DataSource`. When done, remove all properties related to the database and the `@Bean` for the `DataSource.

You can then simply modify your `getSessionFactory` method (I would remove the `get` part btw).

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);   
    sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());    
    sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(com.aaaa.Example.class);
    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

This will already cleanup your configuration.

Now if your `messageSource` is using `messages` as a basename you can even remove the `messageSource` bean as Spring Boot provides one by default. If you have another base name specify it by adding the `spring.messages.basename=your-basename` and `spring.messages.encoding=your-encoding`. (And again another bean bites the dust).

You are using thyme leaf, add the `spring-boot-thymeleaf-starter` remove the beans for Thymeleaf and add the following the `application.properties`.

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

You can also remove the `InternalResourceViewResolver` (looks like your `XmlViewResolver` isn't a bean anyway) Spring Boot has one by default.Also `/resources` is mapped by default and you can let Spring Boot do auto configuring for the web so remove `@EnableWebMvc` as well.

In the end your configuration would look something like this

```
@Configuration
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hbmddl;

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {

        CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        // commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1048576);
        commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10000000);
        return commonsMultipartResolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(com.aaaa.Example.class);
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbmddl);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {

        return new HibernateTransactionManager(getSessionFactory());    
    }
}
```

If you would move to JPA instead of plain hibernate you could even remove all of the hibernate stuff and let spring boot take care of that.

**Note:** You might need to 'exclude`the`HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`in the`@SpringBootApplication`to prevent Spring Boot from detecting the entity manager (if you accidentally happen to have`hibernate-entitymanager` on your classpath as a dependency.

**Note 2:** This is just *ONE* approach it isn't *THE* approach as there are multiple ways leading to integrating Spring Boot into an existing application

**Note 3:** YMMV depending on the used Spring version you might need to refactor parts of your application. If you are still on an old version of spring you might run into deprecated classes for instance.

Comment: Thanks Deinum for your valuable reply . I will change my code according to your reply.

Comment: And after every step test of course :). I did it from the top of my head so I probably missed a couple of things, but it should give you at least some guidance.